# Multilanguage backend interface

Tags: multi-language, plugin-polylang

I manage a site that is available in 5 languages, including English. The Polylang plugin is used to achieve this. The problem is that I only understand two of the languages, and it's cumbersome to manage when you have to look up all the words in Google Translate.

Is there a way that I can display the English title of the page, like on the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hovering over the pen icons on the right hand side will display the page title in the respective language as a tooltip.

[image]